# Tweepy bot to tweet DMs

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I would like to make a bot on twitter to use with my friends, it would be like a spotted. The bot would need to tweet the messages they send on his dm. On the internet I found this function, but I don't know if it's right, nor how to close this puzzle, can someone help me?

```
api.list_direct_messages()
```

Comment: That's not really enough code to make sense, but no, that will not work, because Twitter userstreams API no longer exists. You need to use the Account Activity API to receive and respond to Direct Messages (tweepy does not support this)

Comment: `api.list_direct_messages()` should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the DM messages with

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('api_key', 'api_secret')
auth.set_access_token('access_token', 'token_secret')

api = tweepy.API(auth)
messages = get_api().list_direct_messages(count=5)
```

The code above would rin in a thread to fetch the messages every x minutes.
Once you have the messages you can process the list, send the tweet and delete the DMs (to avoid processing it again).

```
for message in messages:
  text = message.message_create["message_data"]["text"]
  api.update_status(f'Tweet DM content: {text}'
  # remove DM
  api.destroy_direct_message(message.id)
```

Comment: This will work, but for real time interactions you’ll want to build something using the webhook-based Account Activity API, rather than polling. You’d also need to read Twitter’s [automation policy](https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-automation) to avoid having your app restricted.